# AsyncTaskRunner in debug mode exits the app?

Tags: android

Don't know why when I run the app on debug mode, it will exit the app at the end of the doInBackground.

Here is the code:

```
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {

        try
        {
            Log.e("SQLMainActivity", "Inicio do try");
            Connection con;
            Statement stmt;
            ResultSet rs;
            String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            String conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("server") + ":" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("port") + "/" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("dbname") +
                    ";instance=" + GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("instance");
            Class.forName(driver);
            Log.e("SQLMainActivity", "Consegui meter a diver como deve ser");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("user"), GlobalVars.SQLServerInfo.get("pass"));
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Pda_Documentos ORDER BY Ordem";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            Log.e("SQLMainActivity", "Consegui executar a query como deve ser");
            PDADocumentos tempDoc;
            // TODO ** Informação ** De lembrar que ao ser adicionados campos aos documentos temos que actualizar esta parte do codigo
            while (rs.next())
            {
                tempDoc = new PDADocumentos();
                tempDoc.setID(rs.getString("Tipo"));
                tempDoc.setNome(rs.getString("Nome"));
                GlobalVars.PDADocInfo.put(rs.getString("Tipo"), tempDoc);
            }
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            Log.e("SQLMainActivity", "Fechei com sucesso a ligação");
            SQLConDocuments = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SQLConfig", "Não consegui fazer a ligação");
            Log.e("SQLConfig", e.toString());
        }
        FillDocumentsToMemory();
        return "done";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.config_connection_title),
                getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.config_connection_message));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text)
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Messagem enviada com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

During the Debug, pressing F8 (Android Studio) when it reach the line "return "done";" of doInBackground the app closes, even the button "Stop" on android studio goes gray (can't be pressed, only happens when the program is closed

BtW forgot to add, I'm calling the runner here:

```
        if (checkFileIfExist("dbHelper.db"))
        {
            // Metodo Que irá passar PDA_Documentos para o mapa e também actualizar a base de dados SQL
            Log.e("AsyncTask","Buscar info principal para andar");
            AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
            runner.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.config_sqlitle_message)
                    .setTitle(R.string.alert_titles_warning)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.general_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                        {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                            finishAndRemoveTask();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Another thing to add, this only happens if I put a breakpoint inside the doInBackground, if it doesn't have a breakpoint there will be no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seams that is a problem with Android it self, the bug as been reported it seems https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37081686